# Chrome or Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, 12.10, chromium, browser, google

After installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop, I went to download Chrome and got an error saying it was packaged badly or something, so I read up about it and found out about Chrome, and most people suggest that Ubuntu users should use Chromium over Chrome, although a lot is down to preference.

I read that Chromium is almost a 'beta' build for Chrome, but is quicker etc. as it has the newest features.

Is it still safe to use, for say banking etc.?
Should I ignore the error and just get Chrome anyway?

What do you use?

Comment: I don't like to get into this Chromium versus Chrome business because it's been done to death @ askubuntu.com.

Comment: I'm new here so I hadn't seen it before, and that question linked is 2 years old, things may have changed since then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used Chrome for a while but switched to Chromium, mostly because I read that "Chromium is the open source web browser project from which Google Chrome draws its source code". I figured: if I can use open source, I will.

There aren't too many differences, although there are a few. This is what Wikipedia says Google adds to Chromium to make Chrome:

- Integrated Flash Player
- Built-in PDF viewer
- Built-in print preview and print system
- The Google name and a different logo
- An auto-update system called GoogleUpdate
- An opt-in option for users to send Google their usage statistics and crash reports
- RLZ tracking when Chrome is downloaded as part of marketing promotions and distribution partnerships

However, this is all fairly easily compensated and I use Chromium without any problems.

For more info, see [Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29#Differences_from_Google_Chrome) and [Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome).